# How to override empty strings with NULL on load data from CSV with liquibase?

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

When I try to load data from a csv file on a column with numeric type, if a value is empty("") it is not read as null, but empty string, which does not work.

How can I override these values with null?  I do not want to modify the csv file.

Comment: CSV can not distinquish between `null` and the empty string `""`.

Comment: It seems your only chance is to either modify the CSV file [quote from the manual](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html) "*A value of NULL in a cell will be converted to a database NULL rather than the string ‘NULL’*" or run an UPDATE afterwards `update the_table set the_column = null where the_column = ''`

Comment: `COPY "tablename" FROM 'filename' WITH CSV NULL AS '""';`

Comment: It does not see the file on specified path. This sql is executed by the postgres server,  so I don't know the path of the file. Also, the "\copy" command,  which should allow us to execute from the client side, is not recognized as a sql command.

Comment: Just an idea: You could create your own extension. Extend the [`Change`](https://liquibase.jira.com/wiki/spaces/CONTRIB/pages/1998880/Change) (resp. the `LoadaDataChange` class and override `generateStatements` methods. In there call super and change values in the generated sql. Well, now that I've written it.... maybe not...